# Scroll to Top in iframe without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to Scroll To top of the iframe without reloading. I have a form within iframe. When click the submit button, it should be moved to top of the iframe without reloading.

I tried with the following codes,

top.location.href = '#top';

window.parent.location.hash = "#top";

but they are reloading. I should not reload the page. Because, when it loads , validation error message from javascript becomes invalid.Please helpful to achieve this one.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `window.scrollTo(xPos, yPos)` like `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

If you want this animated, then you can use jQuery's `animate` function, and set the `scrollTop` to `0`, like this:

```
$('iframe').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.I tried with that too. I need to scroll my iframe from bottom to top without reloading.window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0);      parent.scrollTo(0,0); they are working. but reloads the page which affects the javascript validation

Comment: I have added javascript validation for my form. I have placed the form inside the iframe.

Comment: I used the animate function. It takes me to the top. But it reloads the page.